# Blade view shows richtext content (stored in mysql table) as not-responsive

Tags: laravel-blade, richtext

I stored a rich-text content in to MySQL table. When I tried to show that content in (Laravel) Blade template, It shows well (with the formatings done by html tags it has) but it is not responsive, as it went beyond the outer div tag (class="col-lg-8"). I understood that the issue is, the content's html tags are considered rather the outer div tag's "style" formats. Are there any possibilities to accomplish this..?

I used htmlspecialchars_decode() also, but nothing changed.
I used {!! and !!} to exclude html tags...

echo htmlspecialchars_decode($article->content);

{!!$article->content); !!}

The content has to obey the outer div's style "first", then the formatting it has itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I did it. I just put a str_replace() method in the relevant controller as it replaces the string (that richtext has) "width:1200px" as empty, them it becomes OK. So wherever the paragraph tries to behave the width "1200px", php won't allow it..! Finally the formatted text falling inside the responsive div tag. Hooray...!